# setting JLAbel's text at load

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jlabel

I'm trying to display which OS my JFrame application runs on a JLabel component. I can easily detect OS type. How can i send it to JLabel on my gui to display OS's name? Below you can see my GUI and code. I need to display OS's name on JLabel4 component. (It's shown as "..." in the GUI)

**my GUI**:

[image]

**Janus.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package janus;

import my.janus.JanusUI;

/**
 *
 * @author Timur
 */

public class Janus {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    private static String OS = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();

    public Janus(){
        JanusUI gui = new JanusUI();
        gui.setVisible(true);
        detectOS();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Janus obj = new Janus();
    }

    // this one prints OS type
    public static void detectOS(){
        if(isMac()){
            System.out.println("operating system detected as Mac");
        }
        else if(isWindows()){
            System.out.println("operating system detected as Windows");
        }
        else if(isLinux()){
            System.out.println("operating system detected as Linux");
        }
        else if(isSolaris()){
            System.out.println("operating system detected as Solaris");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("isMac() returned false");
        }
    }

    // detecting os as mac
    public static boolean isMac(){
        return (OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0);
    }

    // detecting os as windows
    public static boolean isWindows(){
        return (OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0);
    }

    // detecting os as unix-linux
    public static boolean isLinux(){
        return (OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0);
    }

    // detecting os as solaris
    public static boolean isSolaris(){
        return (OS.indexOf("mac") >= 0);
    }
}
```

**JanusUI.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package my.janus;

/**
 *
 * @author Timur
 */
public class JanusUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form JanusUI
     */
    public JanusUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Enter time:");

        jButton1.setText("Start");

        jButton2.setText("Pause");

        jButton3.setText("Clear");

        jButton4.setText("Lock");

        jLabel2.setText("Remaining Time:");

        jLabel3.setText("Your OS:");

        jLabel4.setText("...");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 88, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addComponent(jLabel2))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 39, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 1, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 75, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addContainerGap(13, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addContainerGap(177, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JanusUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JanusUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JanusUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JanusUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JanusUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a setter method in JanusUI `setOSText()`

```
public void setOSText(string) {
    jLabel4.setText(string);
}
```

Have `detectOS` return the OS name:

```
public static String detectOS(){
    if(isMac()){
            System.out.println("operating system detected as Mac");
            return "Mac";
        }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Call setOSText from your constructor:

```
public Janus(){
        JanusUI gui = new JanusUI();
        gui.setVisible(true);
        String os = detectOS();
        gui.setOSText(os);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `JanusUI` add a method `setOs(String OS)`

after initialize a new instance of your `JanusUI`, call the setter method

e.g.

```
public void setOs(String OS) {

      this.jLabel4.setText(OS);

}
```

put this into your `Janus` constructor

```
public Janus(){
        JanusUI gui = new JanusUI();
        gui.setOs(OS);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        detectOS();
    }
```

this should work.